# Please help me to find s memory leak in this objective-C method (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiimage

Ok, I'm really desperate to find this. I'm new in Objective-C and don't have enough experience in pointers managing. I know an important memory leak is here, because executing this code multiple times result in a bunch of memory warnings, but can't find where is it or how to solve it.

The method below gets some data from fixed arrays and create a group of images from it. It's updating a fixed amount of images, but only the first 'n' counts, so the rest are filled with transparent little images (to clear the previous ones).

(I suspect of the UIImages created every execution because the memory is consumed too fast during execution.)

I've already tried to add to the line

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
```

an autorelease, because I suspected of the images created every time this code is called, and I suppoused that autorelease should be called when routeView[indexAux].image pointed to the new created images. I think that could work, but it eventually ended in "message sent to deallocated instance" error.

Also tried to replace that part with:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
routeView[indexAux].image = [img copy];
[img release];
```

...so the only existing copy of the deceased img variable exist in routeView[i].image, and were eventually overwrited by the next execution. But ended getting the same memory leak. Any help or hint is welcome. Thanks in advance!

```
-(void) update:(NSArray*) arr{
    int indexAux = 0;
    for(NSNumber* i in arr){
        int index = [i integerValue];
        CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
                                                  routeView[indexAux].frame.size.width,
                                                  routeView[indexAux].frame.size.height,
                                                  8,
                                                  4 * routeView[indexAux].frame.size.width,
                                                  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                                  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

        self.lineColor = [coloresDeSeccion[index] copy];

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

        for(int i = sections[index]; i <= sections[index + 1]; i++) {
            CLLocation* location = [routes objectAtIndex:i];
            CGPoint point = [mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:routeView[indexAux]];
            if(i == sections[index]) { //¿Que hacías aquí?
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, routeView[indexAux].frame.size.height - point.y);
            } else {
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, routeView[indexAux].frame.size.height - point.y);
            }
        }

        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];

        routeView[indexAux].image = img;

        CGContextRelease(context);
        indexAux++;
    }

    for(int i = indexAux; i < 15; i++){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(36, 36), NO, 0.0);
        UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        routeView[indexAux].image = blank;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create an image here:

```
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

This function includes the word `Create` in it. According to the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html), you must release it:

```
CFRelease(image);
```

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! Thanks, man, you saved my life!! I was a little confused about in being an structure, 'cause it doesn't support the "release" method, but for some reason I didn't figure it has it's own release method. Thanks again.